# What's the best video for explaining "binding" to "this" in React?

Tags: reactjs, debugging

I see this a lot...
this.function = this.function.bind(this)

Is there a good video that explains what's happening here? 
Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming you are already using babel to compile your code, why not use the class properties feature and then you define your class method as an arrow function and don't have to bind it in the constructor. https://medium.com/@joshblack/writing-a-react-component-in-es2015-a0b27e1ed50a#.igcom8sgv gives step by step how to set it up then you write your class methods like such : `myFunction = () => { // do stuff }` and the arrow function binds this appropriately.

Comment: software recommendations are off topic.

Comment: Thank you so much finalfreq!!! This is exactly what I needed. If you make this an answer, I'll select as the right answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are already using babel to compile your code, why not use the class properties feature and then you define your class method as an arrow function and don't have to bind it in the constructor. https://medium.com/@joshblack/writing-a-react-component-in-es2015-a0b27e1ed50a#.igcom8sgv gives step by step how to set it up then you write your class methods like such : `myFunction = () => { // do stuff }` and the arrow function binds this appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

WebStorm is most powerfull IDE for React: understand JSX Harmony, Components, props, state, etc. Has code auto formatting, understand npm scriptsm etc.

for free..

I always used Brackets, but when I started working with React I had to switch to a different editor due to the complete lack of support by Brackets.

I'm now using Atom with ton of plugins to work with React and be comfortable, these are the ones needed to work with React:

**language-babel** by gandm

**linter-eslint** by AtomLinter

**react** by orktes
the latter, especially, has an awesome support for React and JSX stuff.